# Forge convertion to obj only returning svf

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm following the step-by-step instructions [Extract Geometry tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/) , and everything *seems* to work fine, except when I check the manifest after posting the job, it always returns the manifest for the initial conversion to SVF.

The tutorial specifically states that you must convert to SVF first. This takes a few seconds to a few minutes, starting at 0% and going until 100%. I await completion, and when I post the second job with the following payload (verifying that the payload is as requested)

```
let objPayload = {
    "input": {
      "urn": job.urn  # urn retrieved from the file upload / svf conversion
    },
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "obj"
          , "advanced": {
            "modelGuid": metaData[0].guid,
            "objectIds": [-1]
          }
        }]
    }
  }
```

( where `metaData[0].guid` is the provided guid from Step 1's call to `/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urn}/metadata`)
,  then the job actually *starts* at about 99%. It sometimes takes a few moments to complete, but when it does, the call to retrieve the manifest returns the previous manifest where the output format is marked at "svf".

The [POST Job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST) page states that

> Derivatives are stored in a manifest that is updated each time this endpoint is used on a source file.

So I would expect the the returned manifest to be updated to return the requested 'obj'. But it is not.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the URN or the seed file name. Not all format can be translated to OBJ - see that [table](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/) for allowed translation. Now it seems your manifest has some progress status; it means there should be a section describing the OBJ job progress in the children list. Could you provide me a copy of the manifest before the job, during the translation where there is a %, and after the translation failed. I would take a look in our log file for you. Please send by email to cyrille at autodesk.com

Comment: The translation table is interesting -- it isn't mentioned anywhere in the Extract Geometry tutorial, which is written to imply that anything converted to SVF first was translatable to OBJ. That would explain the result. However, the API _drastically_ needs better feedback messages to say "no, that's not a valid output for that input" instead of just processing a different job and giving you the results. 
Either way, the original source file was IFC.

Comment: I tried it with a RVT file and it did the OBJ conversion. 
*Please* change the endpoint response - it is exceptionally misleading as it is.

Answer (score 0):

As [Cyrille pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533084/forge-convertion-to-obj-only-returning-svf?noredirect=1#comment95874778_54533084), the translate job only works consistently when translating to SVF. If translating to OBJ, you can only do so from specific formats, listed in [this table](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/).

At the time of this writing, if you request a job outside that table (eg IFC->OBJ), it will still accept your job, and simply not do it. So if you're following the "Extract Geometry" tutorial, when you request the manifest, it is still pointing to the original SVF translation.